# CHECK constraint to restrict the registration date to dates after August 26, 2005

Tags: sql, date, datetime

Need some help with this:

> Create a table called TEMP_STUDENT with the following columns and
>   constraints: a column STUD_ID for the student ID and is the primary
>   key, a column FIRST_NAME for student first name, a column LAST_NAME
>   for student last name, a column ZIP that is a foreign key to the ZIP
>   column in the ZIPCODE table of the Student Database Schema, and a
>   column REGISTRATION_DATE that is NOT NULL and has a CHECK constraint
>   to restrict the registration date to dates after August 26, 2005.  ALL
>   CONSTRAINTS MUST BE NAMED.  Both the first_name and last_name columns
>   are required.

I got this:

```
CREATE TABLE Temp_Student
(STUD_ID NUMBER (8,0),
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
ZIP VARCHAR2(5),
REGISTRATION_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT STUD_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY(STUD_ID),
CONSTRAINT ZIP_FK FOREIGN KEY (ZIP)
REFERENCES ZIPCODE (ZIP),
CONSTRAINT chk_REGISTRATION_DATE CHECK (REGISTRATION_DATE> REGISTRATION_DATE 'TO DATE('26-AUGUST-2005'))
);
```

Any help with the last constraint, it would be much appreciated i have no idea what im doing.

keep getting this message:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_REGISTRATION_DATE CHECK (REGISTRATION_DATE> REGISTRATION_DATE 'TO DATE('26-AUGUST-2005')')
                                                                             *
ERROR at line 10: 
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting gives away what the error is: a misplaced ' is interpreted as a string literal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several errors in your expression:

1. It's `to_date()` not `to date()` (note the underscore)
2. a function call must not be put into single quotes, so it's `to_date(..)`, not `'to_date(...)'`
3. you repeated the column after the `>` operator which is also wrong.

So the correct expression is this:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_REGISTRATION_DATE 
   CHECK (REGISTRATION_DATE > TO_DATE('2005-08-26', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

Note that you should ***always*** specify a format when using `to_date()` otherwise the conversion is subject to the NLS setting of the server and the client and might produce strange errors.

And even if you use a format mask you should not use a literal that depends on the current NLS *language*. `AUGUST` might not work for all languages as the month name. It's better to use the month number.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE Temp_Student
(STUD_ID NUMBER (8,0),
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
ZIP VARCHAR2(5),
REGISTRATION_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT STUD_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY(STUD_ID),
CONSTRAINT ZIP_FK FOREIGN KEY (ZIP)
REFERENCES ZIPCODE (ZIP),
CONSTRAINT chk_REGISTRATION_DATE CHECK (REGISTRATION_DATE> TO_DATE('26-AUGUST-2005'))
)
```