# SQL - timestamp Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a condition within a GP database whereby I must only be able to insert appointments which are equal to or greater than todays date.

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE Appointment_Table(
AppointmentID Number(6) NOT NULL Primary Key,
DateAndTime Timestamp(0) NOT NULL,
Check (DateAndTime >= (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')));
```

This is the error I am getting:

> ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL

Would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: If you are using Oracle, you cannot use `sysdate` (or related functionality) in a `check` constraint.

Comment: similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863954/check-constraint-to-restrict-the-registration-date-to-dates-after-august-26-200 .... wrap the (date1, format) inside to_date

Comment: Current date or current timestamp?

Comment: @dnoeth current timestamp. Inserted date must be equal to or greater than todays timestamp.

Comment: Your check should look like this: `Check (DateAndTime >= current_timestamp(0))`, but it's not allowed in Oracle anyway.

Comment: alternatively, you may try to create an insert trigger which raises error when `:new.DateAndTime  < trunc(sysdate)`.

Comment: Use Oracle Documentation and jump to the section "Restrictions on Check Constraints". Hope this gives you a complete idea.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm

Comment: The constraint, exactly as written, makes no sense. You certainly want "current time **when the row is inserted**", but that's not what `SYSDATE` means. If Oracle were to allow this constraint, it should be able to verify that it is satisfied **at any time in the future**. If it would check at any time after the date value you are inserting, the constraint would be violated. Do you see why Oracle can't allow something like that? Check the constraint in a trigger, or in your application, or write an `INSERT` statement with a WHERE clause and put the condition there, not in the table.

Answer (score 4):

Data type `date` is enough to store day, hour, minute and seconds. No need for `timestamp`. Also, `primary key` gives you `not null` for free, so no need to specify that.

Use a trigger, not a check constraint, since Oracle don't allow `sysdate` (time now) in `check`.

```
create table a (
  id    number(6) primary key,
  d     date      not null
);

create or replace trigger t_a_ins before insert on a
for each row when ( new.d < sysdate )
begin raise_application_error( -20000, 'Forbidden!'); end;
/

insert into a values (1, sysdate+1);
insert into a values (2, sysdate-1);
```

The first insert is ok.

The second results in error `ORA-20000: Forbidden!`. Choose numbers between -20000 and -20999 to define your own ORA-errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Then, @Ibrahim, you're doing it wrong because I've just tested it and it works exactly how you described in your question.

Comment: @Ibrahim - "this is not working for me" is not a technical description of the issue you encountered. How do you expect anyone to be able to help you based on **that** information? Do you need help, or don't you?

Comment: @Littlefoot - Ill try again. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to have a field on the table which is populated with the current date/time, and to then have the check constraint check the 'current-date-and-time' field. Let's call that new field ADD_DATE. So your table becomes:

```
CREATE TABLE Appointment_Table
 (AppointmentID        Number(6)
    NOT NULL
    Primary Key,
  DateAndTime          Timestamp(0)
    NOT NULL,
  ADD_DATE             DATE
    DEFAULT SYSDATE
    NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT APPOINTMENT_TABLE_CK1
    CHECK(DateAndTime >= ADD_DATE));
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33bbe/1)

Note that as shown in the SQLFiddle you don't need to supply a value for `ADD_DATE`, or even mention it in the INSERT. The default value of SYSDATE is applied when the column is omitted in the INSERT statement. So in the SQLFiddle the INSERT statements used only mention APPOINTMENTID and DATEANDTIME:

```
INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT_TABLE (APPOINTMENTID, DATEANDTIME)
  VALUES (1, TO_DATE('01-MAY-2017 08:30:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT_TABLE (APPOINTMENTID, DATEANDTIME)
  VALUES (2, TO_DATE('01-MAY-2018 17:30:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

After executing the above statements the table looks like:

```
APPOINTMENTID   DATEANDTIME             ADD_DATE
1               2018-05-01 08:30:00.0   2018-03-11T03:15:00Z
2               2018-05-01 17:30:00.0   2018-03-11T03:15:00Z
```

If you change one of the `DateAndTime` values to 2017 instead of 2018 and then execute the statement you'll get an error similar to

```
ORA-02290: check constraint (USER_4_85DBA.APPOINTMENT_TABLE_CK1) violated
```

This demonstrates that the constraint is working as expected.

Best of luck.

Comment: You can easily bypass this constraint by `INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT_TABLE (APPOINTMENTID, DATEANDTIME, ADD_DATE)
  VALUES (2, TO_DATE('01-MAY-2017 17:30:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), DATE '1900-01-01');`

Comment: Being able to bypass is a feature, not a bug. I you're migrating from one database to another you'd want to keep the original `ADD_DATE`'s not the sysdate's from when you migrated.